# Problem with Adding/Editing inline Foreign Key Fields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin, user-profile

I have two models, School and UserProfiles, where UserProfiles has a ForeignKey to School. In the Django Admin, I want to be able to pick a school and have it display all the userprofiles that have a foreign key to it.

The way that I did this was to create a new Inline, with the model being the UserProfile, and adding it to the new SchoolAdmin and registering it.

My problem arises when I go to add a new userprofile. What happens is that I pick an existing user from the dropdown box and click save. However, I then get an error stating that a "User Profile with this User already exists."

It seems that upon saving, it tries to create a new User Profile for the user I pick. Am I going about doing this the wrong way?

Here is the code that I have set up to auto-create the user profiles when a user is created.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
"""Create the UserProfile when a new User is saved"""
    print "User Profile Creation: False"
    if created:
        print "User Profile Creation: ", created
        UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)



post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

EDIT: As a side-note, how can I go about tracing the program flow for debugging? I find it difficult to deal with just print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have set up wrong.  However, the error message should be the clue.  At some point you've created a userprofile for User X and then you've tried to create another.  It's important to note that django does not autocreate profiles for users so this has to be code that you've written.

Without seeing code I'm just shooting in the dark here though.  Keep in mind their are multiple ways you could be creating these profiles such as perhaps you registered the post_save signal on the user model.

As for tracing:
http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Or for some cool after the fact crash debugging you could try http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/ with it's implementation of the werkzeug debugger build in http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/runserver_plus.html

Comment: I've added the code that I use for auto-creating the user profiles. However, it's interesting that neither of my print statements get executed when I get the error.

Comment: Yeah you have something else going on somewhere else most likely because that seems like it would be a safe call to make with the get_or_create, so most likely something else in your code (or a 3rd party app) is doing something is shouldn't.

Comment: The only 3rd party app I'm using is South, to handle migrations. Not sure if this would be the problem.

Comment: I did a manage.py reset on my tables and it works now. Must have been some strange thing having to do with South.